# Get the first launch date of an app in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

How can I get the date when a Cordova app was first opened by a user on his phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They only way I can think is to save that data in some storage, server or locale.

One sample

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("firstLaunch") == null) {
         window.localStorage.setItem("firstLaunch", date().toString());
    }
}
```

Now you can access that value with `window.localStorage.getItem("firstLaunch")`

Take in mind that some operative systems can delete localstorage, so if this is a important data, save better in a SQLite or Server Side

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.